# Catching an exception as a response of an actor in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

The following function invokes an actor:

```
def read ()  = {

  val system = ActorSystem(Constant.actorSystem)
  val manageData = system.actorOf(Props[ManageData], name = "theactor")

  val num = -1
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(60 seconds)
  val future = manageData ? num
  val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration)
}
```

Within `manageData` the child process throws an exception:

```
throw new Exception("Negative number")
```

how to catch it in `read()` ?

Comment: Throwing an exception will restart the actor, make a parent actor and do all the work in child actor and handle the exception thrown by child actor in its parent by overriding its supervision strategy.

Comment: So what's the best practice to return an error from an actor to the caller?

Comment: Either pass the information to the sender by sending it a message or handle this exception in parent of this actor and supervise it accordingly.

Comment: I'd just expand on the comment of @curious that if the error is something unexpected - like a runtime exception - it should be handled in the parent's supervision strategy. But if the error has business semantics, it may well not be an error or an exception and should be sent back as a message to the `sender()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I leave my way of dealing with it.

If the exception is something that I'm not expecting I usually treat it on the actor supervisor:

```
override val supervisorStrategy =
  OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 10, withinTimeRange = 1 minute) {
    case _: ArithmeticException      => {
      log.error("\n# ArithmeticException -> Resume\n")
      Resume
    }
    // other exceptions
  }
}
```

For other types of error, I tend to respond with an error and deal with it after:

```
case class IError(code:Int, msg:Option[String] = None)

sender ! IError(401, msg= Some("Unauthorized"))
```